# Layout problem with listView

Tags: android, listview, layout

```
I have two `TextView` and below `ListView` with two `TextView`.  
My problem is: How do I set that value from my second `TextView` from `ListView`  be right under second `TextView` which is above `ListView`.  
Can anyone help?

I have 2 tableRows. In first I have 2 textView's: TextViewNameOfProduct and TextViewPriceOfProduct. In second tableRow i have a listView. ListView have also 2 textView's:textViewProduct and textViewPrice.
My problem is that the textViewPrice is not right below TextViewPriceOfProduct...it isn't aligned with TextViewPriceOfProduct. My english is bad and i I'm not sure if I was clear enough...

http://imageupload.org/?d=2ABFEE041

OPIS PROIZVODA is first textView, second is CENA. Under that are elements from listView. How to put 100 below CENA??? How to align that...if you need my xml i will put it here...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODWyj.jpg


<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow7">
            <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView   android:text="OPIS PROIZVODA" 
                        android:id="@+id/textViewOpisProizvoda" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
            </TextView> 
            <TextView   android:text="CENA" 
                        android:id="@+id/textViewCena" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
            </TextView> 
            </LinearLayout>
      </TableRow>
<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow8">
             <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <ListView               
                android:id="@+id/listViewPonuda" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:visibility="visible"                                
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                >
              </ListView>
              </LinearLayout>         
      </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Would you add in a picture? Because right now, what you mean is... undecipherable.

Comment: Be little clear.We are unable to get what you are asking exactly and what is your situation.Will you please describe little detail.

Comment: Maybe you need to create a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Include a picture of what you current have, and describe more clearly what you'd like to achieve, please.

Comment: you want to align 100 right below CENA? then u need to set listview header

Comment: Do you think that I put in the header OPIS PROIZVODA and CENA???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for listview's textview i.e (ListView have also 2 textView's:textViewProduct and textViewPrice.), you can use this layout. You can adjust the second textview by simply padding right as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country_name"
    android:text="textViewProduct"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country_abbrev"
    android:text="textViewPrice"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="30dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On second text view i set padding 50dip and now it looks okey on emulator. My concern is how it would look on phone??? This is my first android app...

Comment: Then use relative layout that would giv your exact requirement.

Comment: Check this link,this would help you:-           http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/